# How to implement ancestry for this specific situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

We have a **Real-Estate** app in which the *User* can be a *Renter* or *Landlord(Owner)*. Renters can search for specific houses listed by the Owners. Renters can also add other persons(friends or acquaintances who are staying with that specific renter). In the app we treat them as ***Coapplicants***.

***Models***

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :renter
  has_one :owner
end

# renter.rb
class Renter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :coapplicants
end

# coapplicant.rb
class Coapplicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :renter
end
```

Now as to increase the number of users for the app,we implemented a ***mailing system*** which sends an Welcome Mail(when the Renter adds a Coapplicant) to signup as a User.And that Coapplicant can choose to be Renter and can add many Coapplicants too. And the process goes on again resulting in increasing the users.

It's like a tree structure and now I want to set-up a perfect **database relations(associations)** to track the users flowing in and through which ***renter/coapplicant*** they are coming.

Now the Current Model structure(not yet developed) looks like this

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :renter
  has_one :owner
end

# renter.rb
class Renter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :coapplicants
  has_many :coapp_renters,
           :through => :coapplicants
  has_many :inverse_coapplicants,
           :class_name => "Coapplicant",
           :foreign_key => "coapp_renter_id"
  has_many :inverse_coapp_renters,
           :through => :inverse_coapplicants,
           :source => :renter
end

# coapplicant.rb
class Coapplicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :renter
  belongs_to :coapp_renter,
             :class_name => "Renter"
end
```

I guess i messed up things a bit. Which *database-relationships(associations)* would be the best for my current situation.

Can someone throw some light on this please.I'm thinking about using the [**ancestry**](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem but how to implement to my current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor your code and make the **co-applicants** just a **renter** that is a child of another **renter**

in your renter model you have to add a "parent_id" to know whom the co-applicants belongs to.

now in your model you can do something like

```
#renter.rb
class Renter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Renter"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Renter" 
end

# Example calls 
Renter.first.children 
Renter.first.parent
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I was thinking the same and will implement your approach.Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I've found that sometimes even a small change in perspective when designing your associations can make them flow a lot more naturally.

You have focused exclusively on person entities; `User.find(1).renter` for example isn't very intuitive, since both models depict essentially the same person.

Instead of trying to model what people **are**, I would try to model what they **have**. In this case, instead of a `User` having a `Renter`, let them have many **`Rentals`**:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rentals,
            foreign_key: 'renter_id'
end

class Rental
  belongs_to :renter,
              class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :property
end
```

I assume here that you have a model `Property` that stands for what is being rented - leave that out if it doesn't exist.

It's the same thing for owners. A `User` becomes an owner just by having `Ownerships`:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships,
            foreign_key: 'owner_id'
end

class Ownership
  belongs_to :owner,
              class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :property
end
```

A co-application is slightly different in that it belongs to a `Rental`:

```rb
class CoApplication
  belongs_to :co_applicant,
              class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :rental
end

class Rental
  has_many :co_applications
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :co_applications,
            foreign_key: 'co_applicant_id'
  has_many :received_co_applications,
            through: :rentals,
            source: :co_applications
end
```

Now your `Users` can be owners, renters, co-applicants - all at the same time. And these associations allow you to capture everything that happened - who signed on whom through what is just a matter of chronological order.

From here on it's a matter of nesting your `has_many :through` associations to get whatever you want.

Want to know the properties a landlord owns?

```rb
has_many :owned_properties,
          through: :ownerships,
          source: :property
```

The rentals to her properties?

```rb
has_many :leases,
          through: :owned_properties,
          source: :rentals
```

The people who rented her properties?

```rb
has_many :renters,
          through: :leases,
          source: :renter
```

Same thing with co-applications. Want to know who co-applied with a user?

```rb
has_many :co_applicants,
          through: :received_co_applications,
          source: :co_applicant
```

Comment: I like your approach. I will use this if my current approach needs to review from the scratch. Thank you :)

Comment: Ah, I thought you were still in the design phase. Well, in this case these changes would have been a bit too sweeping ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a table called Relationship (or something) with two foreign_ids concerning what you want the User and Renter to be able to do with one another (example to be able to "Follow" one another => Follower_id and Following_id). Define methods in your Models related to those ids and then call those methods in your views to display the relations.